# Highcharts 6.0.2: Overlapping labels

Tags: highcharts

New to Highcharts, and was wondering if someone had a solution they'd developed for my issue. Finding when slices of my donut chart are small enough, their value labels overlap/impede on each other - has anyone found a solution before I go pulling it all apart? :)

[image: Highcharts values overlapping]

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: How do you expect your chart to look like? Share the code that you've created up to this point (live demo preferable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with *a* solution...

Originally I was using:

```
options: {
            chart: {
                height: 320,
                plotShadow: false,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                spacingBottom: 10,
                type: 'pie',
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'center',
                symbolRadius: 0,
                floating: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                y: -110
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    showInLegend: true,
                    startAngle: 45,
                    dataLabels: {
                        allowOverlap: false,
                        distance: 10,
                        padding: 2,
                        softConnector: true,
                        className: 'pieLabels ',
                        format: '{y}',
                        useHTML: true,
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    center: ['50%', '50%'],
                    size: '90%',
                    innerSize: '65%',
                    borderColor: 'none'
                }
            },
            series: this.props.series
        }
```

And ended up with :

```
options: {
            chart: {
                height: 320,
                plotShadow: false,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                spacingBottom: 10,
                type: 'pie',
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'center',
                symbolRadius: 0,
                floating: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                y: -100
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    showInLegend: true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        connectorWidth: 0,
                        distance: -25,
                        // overflow: 'none',
                        className: 'pieLabels ',
                        format: '{y}',
                        useHTML: true,
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    center: ['50%', '50%'],
                    size: '100%',
                    innerSize: '60%',
                    borderColor: 'none',
                },
            },
            series: this.props.series
        }
```

Which gave me :

[image: highcharts graph with external labels]